# truncation of values when casting a decimal(38,10) to float in pyspark

Tags: casting, apache-spark-sql, decimal

I have a column of type decimal(38,10) with value as -  2.1400001000
I am trying to cast it to float using cast(FloatType()). this is resulting in truncation of the value to - 2.14

why is this happening and what can I do to load the value as it is. The final column type has to be of float type.

Regards and Thanks,
Lakshmi Venkata Sai Bollineni

Comment: The maximum precision for a float in Java, and therefor spark, is 7.  That's why you are seeing the rounding. Moral of the story is, don't use float.  It's never going to be as accurate as a decimal.

Comment: hi Andrew, thanks for responding. I have changed the type from float to double.